# DNN error "ERROR CONNECTION TO THE DATABASE"

Tags: dotnetnuke

we have a website developed on DNN. Unfortunately our server have crashed and I have setted up a new one. Server that has the DNN installed with the website is a virtual VM and in the host is located the SQL server (The host is a new server). Unfortunately we cannot access the website because the error in the topic appears on the web browser. User in the config file is sa and in the SQL, sa has dbowner right. Can anyone help

Thanks

Comment: It needs some example and configs.

Comment: Typically this would be due to the user not being able to connect.  The best first diagnostic step would be to connect using SSMS and see if you can run queries.  If that works, check for firewall issues

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a DNN issue at this point, but a connectivity issue for SQL Server. So I would recommend you start by leaving DNN out of the mix.

1) Download SQL Server Management Studio on the web server
2) Attempt to login to SSMS on the web server using the SA credentials
3) If that fails, start looking at some of the online tutorials for how to enable remote connections for SQL server. [Here's a quick one I google'd for you](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/).

Once you can get SSMS working, you can plug in those details into the connection string(s) in DNN to get DNN to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Before the crash event, website was working fine. Connection to SMSS is OK and nothing about names or IPs have changed so I think it is related to DNN but need more help